# How to change switch status in state inside a row in a ListView - React Native

Tags: android, ios, listview, react-native, switch-statement

Hello fellow programmers, I am having this problem developing this React-Native app where i am rendering a ListView of 'Services' where in each row it has a Text and a Switch, and I am able to render it but when i tap on the row's switch to change the value it goest back to its initial value real fast, I was wondering how to keep this change of vale but since I am new into this I am pretty clueless of how this is done: so far I have the ListView component where I call my ListItem component, heres my code;

```
class ListView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            servicios: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("token").then((value) => {
            axios.get('http://MYURL/api/servicio/index?token=' + value)
                .then(response => this.setState({ servicios: response.data.servicios }))
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }).done();
    }
    renderList() {
        console.log('here');
        return this.state.servicios.map(servicio =>
            <ListItem key={servicio.id} servicio={servicio} />);
    }

    render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                {this.renderList()}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }

}
```

ListItem.js

```
const ListItem = ({ servicio }) => {
const { nombre, created_at, estatus } = servicio;
const { thumbnailStyle, headerContentStyle, thumbnailContainerStyle, headerTextStyle, imageStyle } = styles;

return (
    <Card>
        <CardSection>
            <View style={thumbnailContainerStyle}>
                <Text style={headerTextStyle}>{nombre}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={headerContentStyle}>
                <Switch value={estatus}/>
            </View>
        </CardSection>
    </Card>
);
export default ListItem;
```

I missed the styles to not make this post too long, I may have the clue that i've got to put the current's row switch status in the State but I dont know how to do it, I would be really glad if you guys could help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change value of the switch you need to change value in the state from which you're rendering the ListView. I haven't tested that and wrote that from the top of my head, but you should achieve it by introducing small changes here and there:

ListItem.js

```
const ListItem = ({ servicio, onToggleSwitch }) => {
  const { nombre, created_at, estatus, id } = servicio;
  const { thumbnailStyle, headerContentStyle, thumbnailContainerStyle, headerTextStyle, imageStyle } = styles;

  return (
    <Card>
        <CardSection>
            <View style={thumbnailContainerStyle}>
                <Text style={headerTextStyle}>{nombre}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={headerContentStyle}>
                <Switch value={estatus} onValueChange={(value) => onToggleSwitch(id, value)} />
            </View>
        </CardSection>
    </Card>
);
export default ListItem;
```

ListView.js

```
class ListView extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            servicios: []
        };
    }

    onToggleSwitch = (id, value) => {
      const servicios = [...this.state.servicios]
      const index = servicios.findIndex(item => item.id === id)
      servicios[index].estatus = value
      this.setState({ servicios })
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        AsyncStorage.getItem("token").then((value) => {
            axios.get('http://MYURL/api/servicio/index?token=' + value)
                .then(response => this.setState({ servicios: response.data.servicios }))
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });
        }).done();
    }
    renderList() {
        console.log('here');
        return this.state.servicios.map(servicio =>
            <ListItem key={servicio.id} servicio={servicio} onToggleSwitch={this.onToggleSwitch} />);
    }

    render() {
        const { navigation } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
            <ScrollView>
                {this.renderList()}
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: THANK YOU, you gave me what I was looking for, although you got a function's name wrong, on ListItem you called onSwitchToggle and in ListView.js is called onToggleSwitch, shouldnt them both be called the same? I am really appreciate it, thank you very much

Comment: @miguelacio yes, they should. my mistake :) I'm glad to help :) PS. I edited code to correct the mistake.